# Android: LinearLayout.addView not rendering added views

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to add two text views to a `LinearLayout` programmatically (in a loop), and then in turn adding that to a `LinearLayout` that's defined in the layout file. The code runs with no errors, and when evaluating getChildCount I get the expected value, but absolutely nothing is rendering on the device.

**XML**:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llNotes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_quarter"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bottom_corners"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin_half"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" />
```

**Java**:

```
for (Note MyNote : foo.GetNotes()) {
            LinearLayout llNoteParent = new LinearLayout(this);
            TextView tvNoteHeader = new TextView(this);
            TextView tvNoteValue = new TextView(this);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            llParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
            llNoteParent.setLayoutParams(llParams);
            llNoteParent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            llNoteParent.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
            llNoteParent.setPadding(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin, R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin, R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvNoteHeaderParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            tvNoteHeaderParams.weight = 1;
            tvNoteHeader.setLayoutParams(tvNoteHeaderParams);
            tvNoteHeader.setPadding(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin_half);
            tvNoteHeader.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.left_text_field));
            tvNoteHeader.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tvNoteHeader.setText(MyNote.GetAbbreviatedText());

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvNoteValueParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            tvNoteValueParams.weight = 1;
            tvNoteValue.setLayoutParams(tvNoteValueParams);
            tvNoteValue.setPadding(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin_half);
            tvNoteValue.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.right_text_field));
            tvNoteValue.setText(MyNote.GetText());

            llNoteParent.addView(tvNoteHeader);
            llNoteParent.addView(tvNoteValue);
            llNotes.addView(llNoteParent);
        }
```

Comment: In addition to the (correct) answers below, I just wanted to note that I was able to convert the dp value in my dimensions file to the int datatype that setPadding requires by using this:

context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot pass number with dp into setPadding method

```
setPadding(R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin, R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin, R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
```

you need to pass integers into setPadding method.

**1-** try something like this

```
llNoteParent.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
tvNoteHeader.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
```

**2-** OR user integer.xml

```
     for (Note MyNote : foo.GetNotes()) {
                LinearLayout llNoteParent = new LinearLayout(this);
                TextView tvNoteHeader = new TextView(this);
                TextView tvNoteValue = new TextView(this);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams llParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                llParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
                llNoteParent.setLayoutParams(llParams);
                llNoteParent.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                llNoteParent.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white));
                llNoteParent.setPadding(R.integer.activity_horizontal_margin, R.integer.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.integer.activity_horizontal_margin, R.integer.activity_horizontal_margin);

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvNoteHeaderParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                tvNoteHeaderParams.weight = 1;
                tvNoteHeader.setLayoutParams(tvNoteHeaderParams);
                tvNoteHeader.setPadding(R.integer.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.integer.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.integer.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.integer.activity_vertical_margin_half);
                tvNoteHeader.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.left_text_field));
                tvNoteHeader.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                tvNoteHeader.setText(MyNote.GetAbbreviatedText());

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams tvNoteValueParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                tvNoteValueParams.weight = 1;
                tvNoteValue.setLayoutParams(tvNoteValueParams);
                tvNoteValue.setPadding(R.integer.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.integer.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.integer.activity_vertical_margin_half, R.integer.activity_vertical_margin_half);
                tvNoteValue.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.right_text_field));
                tvNoteValue.setText(MyNote.GetText());

                llNoteParent.addView(tvNoteHeader);
                llNoteParent.addView(tvNoteValue);
                llNotes.addView(llNoteParent);
 }
```

**NOTE:** Add the values to **integer.xml** file in values.

Comment: That was it, thank you! I'm a bit bewildered as to why the compiler couldn't have pointed this out to me though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use,

```
float horizontalMargin = getResources()
            .getDimension(R.dimen.R.dimen.activity_horizontal_margin);
float verticleMargin = getResources()
            .getDimension(R.dimen.R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin_half);
```

After that set padding,

```
llNoteParent.setPadding(horizontalMargin,verticleMargin, horizontalMargin, horizontalMargin);
tvNoteHeader.setPadding(verticleMargin, verticleMargin, verticleMargin, verticleMargin);
tvNoteValue.setPadding(verticleMargin, verticleMargin, verticleMargin, verticleMargin);
```